# Duplicate the current line in octave

Tags: octave

Is there any Method to duplicate the one line of code in octave GUI. Like in eclipse if we want to duplicate a code of line such as:

int a = 5;

We can press Ctrl+Alt+Down to copy it to the next Line.
So is there any shortcut to do this in octave GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the cursor to the line you want to duplicate, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd> together

TL;DR: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>